# java task provider missing

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In my vs code the java is not supporting. there is some error. I can't understand and can't solve it.

[image: the error showing in the terminal]

[image: the error showing in the terminal]

How should i run java in vs code? I reffered lote of youtube video's and blogs but nothing is working.

guide to proper working java on vs code

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Also, "doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should install the full [Java extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). A good option to start with is according to this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial).

You can tell by your terminal commands that you are running code with the ***Code Runner*** extension. in the absence of special needs, You shouldn't be using ***Code Runner***, it's more efficient to run code using the official Java extension pack.

[image]

Also, as *@readtheentireinternet* said, your class names should match the file names.